# pg_hba.config me muestra error en el servidor1

Tags: postgresql

En un intento de conexion a la base de datos PostgreSQL me muestra el error siguiente:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  no hay una línea en pg_hba.conf para «192.168.0.1», usuario «postgres», base de datos «postgres», SSL activo
FATAL:  no hay una línea en pg_hba.conf para «192.168.0.1», usuario «postgres», base de datos «postgres», SSL inactivo
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes habilitar en el archivo  `pg_hba.conf` una entrada para el usuario `postgres` desde esa IP que te conectas, algo como:

```
host    all             postgres             192.168.0.1/32            md5
```

No olvides hacer un reload del servicio de PostgreSQL para que tome los cambios

Comment: Habilitado en la ruta:

Comment: ¿Pudiste conectar luego del cambio?

Comment: Gracias

Después de tanto intentar logre por realizar la conexión:

1.- Edite el Archivo:
**sudo nano -c /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf**
_linea_68 === listen_addresses = '*'_

2.- Edite el archivo:
 **sudo nano -c /etc/postgresql/11/main/ pg_hba.conf**
_linea_92 === agregue los datos que me ayudastes_

3.- Conexión Remota:

**psql -h 192.168.0.1 -U postgres -d postgres**
_-U == usuario_
_-d == base de datos_